# Android studio gradle build is failing

Tags: android, android-studio

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithInstantRunVerifierForDebug'.

> java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

Comment: Post your build.gradle file here

Comment: Run Analyze->Inspect code for lint then Click group by Severity.It will show lint errors in your project.Resolve it and build again.

Comment: which jdk version is you used

Answer (score 0):

It's your Java JDK version. It's different that that is being built in Android Studio.